# KendoUpload widget duplicate issue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I'm having an kendoUpload widget in a modal window issue - if you close the window and then again open it kendoUpload widget as if makes several instances of some of its part. Thus it will make a as many records and uploads as you open and close the window. What can cause the issue. I tried to destroy the kendoUpload widget each time when the window close but no luck. Maybe because of the wrong syntax ... Any ideas? THX!

[image]

**Now I close and open the modal window again ->**

[image]

**Now I try to upload a file ->**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="UploadFiles" style="display: none">
<h3>Upload your files:</h3>
<div class="demo-section k-content">
    <input name="files" id="files" type="file"/>
</div>
<br/>
<h3>Current files on server:</h3>
<div id="CurrentFilesOnServer">
    <ul class="CurrentFilesOnServerList">

    </ul>
</div>
```

**Modal window:**

```
// Modal Window Upload file to server
    var uploadFilesWindow = $("#UploadFiles").kendoWindow({
        width: "350px",
        modal: true,
        title: "Upload file to server:",
        actions: [
            "Pin",
            "Minimize",
            "Maximize",
            "Close"
        ],
        close: function () {

        }
    }).data("kendoWindow");
```

**JS Upload section:**

```
  // upload file on server
    $(".k-grid-upload")
        .click(function () {
           uploadFilesWindow.center().open();

            function upload () {

       $("#files")
              .kendoUpload({
                  async: {
                      saveUrl: "/api/Grid/UploadFileOnServer",
                      removeUrl: "",
                      autoUpload: true
                  }
            }
      });
});
```

**C# controller:**

```
// Upload file on server

    public string UploadFileOnServer()
    {

        var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0 ?
   HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0] : null;

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            var path = Path.Combine(
                HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/uploads"),
                fileName
            );

            file.SaveAs(path);
        }

       return  file != null ? "/uploads/" + file.FileName : null;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty certain that the code, which initializes the Upload widget, is executed multiple times, leading to duplicate initialisation and the observed problem.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/jquery-initialization#duplicate-initialization

Destroying a Kendo UI widget does not remove the generated HTML markup from the DOM (the only exception is the Window), so destroying the Upload will not help.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/destroy

You need to refactor the code, so that the Upload is initialised only once, just like the Window. Alternatively, destroy and recreate the whole Window, but keep in mind that its DOM will be removed and you will need to add it back.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/layout/window/overview#configuration-Destroy

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code like this and now it works correctly:

**Initialize kendoUpload:**

```
 var kup = $("#files")
        .kendoUpload({
            async: {
                saveUrl: "/api/Grid/UploadFileOnServer",
                removeUrl: "",
                autoUpload: true
            }
        });
```

**Open window & call kendoUpload instance:**

```
    $(".k-grid-upload")
        .click(function () {
           uploadFilesWindow.center().open();
           kup();
        });
```

(Thx to @dimodi !)

Answer (score 0):

You should Disable Drop Zone, it worked for me, see this link from Kendo Ticket: [Disable Drop Zone](https://www.telerik.com/forums/disable-drop-zone-d2cb9464dab7)

kendo.ui.Upload.fn._supportsDrop = function() { return false; }

[Before*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2W9o.png)
[After **](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BCF5.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue in kendo UI Jquery.
I resolved it in Kendo UI Jquery with below code. Please note, my kendoUpload is written in the init() method. Here we are initializing only if kendoUpload does not exist.

```
function init() {
    // Check if the Kendo Upload is already initialized
    if (!$("#upload").data("kendoUpload")) {
        // Initialize Kendo Upload
        $("#upload").kendoUpload({
            // your Kendo Upload configuration options
        });
    }
}
```